# Best way to handle a multi-task file system using an RTOS in embedded C?

Tags: c, filesystems, embedded, rtos, fat

I am using the CMX-RTX RTOS and Elm Chan FatFS. Things work well until tasks line up to hit the file system.

For those familiar with Chan FatFS I have modified the ENTER_FS and LEAVE_FS macros to take and release a resource. If a task tries to enter the FS and the resource is own it will be placed in wait until the resource is released.

I am starting to have doubts that this is the best way of handling accesses to the FS from multiple tasks. I have had multiple instances where the FS generates failures and even simple commands to the SD get incorrect responses. None of these failures occur if I limit only 1 task to accessing the FS.

To get to the main question, what is everyone thoughts/recommendations to multi-task FS access? For example a more refined method I initially used? Or perhaps a singular task that will be flagged by the different tasks to access the FS?

Answer (score 0):

As most accesses are reads, the obvious and simple improvement is multi-reader, single writer. A further improvement would be to treat the root FAT directory special, and create a bypass so that writes elsewhere don't block root directory reads. (This could also include a R/W cache of the root dir)

Answer (score 0):

I use one thread to access my SD-card with FatFS.  It works well, as you say.  I use the main thread to run the file system since it has the largest stack, (since it must run the crt, C++ static ctors and other stuff).  main() becomes a thread, starts all the other threads that run the app and then run a file system loop that processes requests from a producer-consumer queue.

Any thread that requires file operations must queue up an 'FSrequest' object to the FS thread.  The FS thread handles the requests serially as they appear on the queue.  All threads that require FS derive from FSnotifiable, itself a class derived from FSrequest that has a FSnotify method that takes an FSrequest as a parameter.  The FS thread pops the FSrequests from the queue, processes them as requested by a 'command' enum member loads an 'error' member with null or an error string pointer and then calls the FSnotify method with the completed FSrequest as a parameter.

Typically, the FSnotify() signals a semaphore upon which the originating thread is waiting.

EDIT:  AND THAT IS ALL RUBBISH BECAUSE IT'S A C QUESTION:((

I'll try again:

OK, so no classes:(  Declare an 'FSrequest' struct to represent an FS request/response.  It should have an enum to represent the desired operation, and a 'completion' callback function to be filled in the the originating thread.  It would also probably have a buffer pointer, (for those oprations that need a buffer to read/write from/to, or hold an error message is failed), and a success/fail boolean.

Use one thread popping from a producer-consumer queue struct/code to handle the file system.  If a thread wants an FS operation, it needs to declare an FS request, fill in the details and queue it up to the FS thread.  It should point the completion callback to a function that signals a semaphore.  The requesting thread waits on the semaphore for completion notification from the FS thread.  The FS thread performs whatever operation is requested, fills in success/fail/error, and then calls the completion callback.